# full page Background image behind google maps does not appear in the html output

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have an html page which loads the google map.I want to use an image as a background to cover the whole html page. But for some reason the background image does not appear, but the Google map loads in the specified div. my files are following (markerdrop.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="markerdropstyle.css" />    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and markerdroptsyle.css:

```
html{
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
    background:url("images/myimage.jpg") no-repeat center center;

    /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
    min-height:100%;

    /* The Magic */
    background-size:cover;
}

    body{
        /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
        background:url("images/myimage.jpg") no-repeat center center;

        /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
        min-height:100%;

        /* The Magic */
        background-size:cover;
        min-height:100%;
    }

    #map-canvas {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
          }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your final result should look like. Maybe add a jsfiddle of your project?

Comment: thanks for your comment...after trying different things i figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Changing the CSS to following worked for me:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/myimage.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    }  

 div#map-canvas
    {
     width:500px;
     height:250px;

     }
```